# Laravel adding a global condition on an eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I get the `invoices` in multiple pages using a single query.

**Query Code:**

```
$invoices = ImportInvoice::withSupplier() -> withCreatedByAndUpdatedBy() -> orderedName() -> paginate(10);
```

### PROBLEM:

I have added `approve` field in database which is `boolean` value weather the invoice is approve ***(1)*** or not approve ***(0)***.

So now I have to add `where('approve', 1)` to get the approved invoices.

Problem is that I will edit this eloquent in multiple controllers.

### Question is:

Is there a way to add this where condition in the model?
Plus sometimes I want to return the ***Not Approved*** invoices.

It is similar to **Soft Delete** created by Laravel.

`Soft delete` does not get returned when calling a query but if I want to call it I just call `withTrashed()` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes you can do like that open your `ImportInvoice` Model

first **import(add)** this class ..

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

and add this `boot` method

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('approve', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('approve',  1);
        });
    }
```

now by default get **approved invoices**

```
 ImportInvoice::get()
```

and you want to Approved and  Not Approved invoices then do like that

```
ImportInvoice::withoutGlobalScope('approve')->get();
```

for more information read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#global-scopes)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through global scopes in Laravel . open your `ImportInvoice` Model

first **import(add)** this class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

and add this boot method

```
protected static function booted()
{
        static::addGlobalScope('approve', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('approve',  1);
        });
}
```

now by default get **approved invoices**

```
ImportInvoice::get();
```

and you want to Approved and Not Approved invoices then do like that

```
ImportInvoice::withoutGlobalScope('approve')->get();
```

for more information read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes)